# Mapping coordinates from plane given by normal vector to XY plane (From 3D to 2D)

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, rotation, plane

I have set of 3-dimensional dots, which lie on the plane with arbitrary normalized normal **N'** and the point through which this plane passes **M (0, 0, 0)** .

And to display it I need to map this coordinates to XY plane (convert from 3D to 2D).

First, what i do it's calculate dot product with **N'** and **Z-axis** as rotation angle **Theta**(**N' ∙ Vec3f(0, 0, 1)**) and multiply it by **PI** and divide by **180** (cos functions take radians).

Then i calculate cross product of **N'** and **Z-axis** (**N' x Vec3f(0, 0, 1)**) to get a new vector **R** *(an arbitrary axis around which we will rotate our points)*.

Then i normalize **R' = R / ||R||**.

And pass it to next matrix:

[image]

But at the output, after matrix-vector multiplication, my points do not become two-dimensional(**z is not 0**), tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give us **N'**, theta, **R**, **R'**, and the coordinates of the troublesome dot (before and after the transformation), so that we can check your arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get angle between N and Z, you have to calculate arccosine of dot product (assuming N is unit length)

```
Theta = acos(N.dot.Z)
```

and result is in radians.

Comment: Yeah, N' is unit length. I tried to use you solution but z is still not equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code for your problem. I'm not the author of this code, just grab it from another stackoverflow thread that I already forgot.

```
# Plane equation ax+by+cz =0 , normal vector = (a,b,c)
# oldpoints is your original 3D dot, newpoints is their values in xy plane after rotation transformation
import numpy as np
import vg
from pytransform3d.rotations import matrix_from_axis_angle
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as Rot

vector = np.array([a, b, c])
vector = vg.normalize(vector)
axis = vg.perpendicular(vector, vg.basis.z)
angle = vg.angle(vector, vg.basis.z, units='rad')    
a = np.hstack((axis, (angle,)))
R = matrix_from_axis_angle(a)    
r = Rot.from_matrix(R)
newpoints = r.apply(oldpoints)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).